# How to remove the minimum number from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

//Here is my code:

```
    function removeSmallest(arr) {
      var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
      return arr.filter((e) => {return e != min});
      }

      console.log(removeSmallest([2,1,3,5,4], [5,3,2,1,4], [2,2,1,2,1]));
```

/*The issue is that I need the third array to output [2,2,2,1].  The code is actually doing what I am telling it to do by removing the smallest number in each array but for the sake of my problem, I need it to only take out one of the ones(if that makes sense).  Appreciate any help!
*/

Comment: Do you want to remove the minimum number found by collective of all the arrays and then remove it from whichever array it is present? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: sure, so the instructions say to remove the smallest value.  Do not mutate the original array/list. If there are multiple elements with the same value, remove the one with a lower index.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your logic slightly. You find the minimum number in the array, then use that to find the first index of that number, and remove that specific number.

```
function removeSmallest(arr) {
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(min), 1);

  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove only the first occurrence in the array then somehow like that:

```
function removeSmallest(arr) {
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  var count = 0;
  return arr.filter((e) => { 
      if(e != min || count > 0) {
          return true;
      }
      else if(e == min) {
          count++;
          return false;
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Good stuff.  Should have thought of an if/else!  Thanks!